# Notes 10x Duplication (Without iCloud)

Tags: macos, notes.app

My notes.app is going crazy. When I create a new Note and then hit save, the note is not only duplicated but 10x duplicated.

I have icloud sync deactivated. As far as I can see, the note is duplicated for each word in the file with more than one letter.

What can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to close **Notes**  and delete `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Notes.plist`.

Relaunch **Notes** to see if the same problem exits.

### Update

This [method suggested](http://woikr.com/apple/fix-icloud-duplicate-notes-issues-in-mountain-lion/) will remove all your local Notes and resync with the notes stored in iCloud. Just for record:

1. Open your favorite Terminal. (If that sounded weird, just open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
2. Quit Notes.app.
3. Enter `rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes.` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Hi. I tried your suggestion but that does nothing. It still creates one new note per word.

Comment: You might want to try this [suggestion](http://woikr.com/apple/fix-icloud-duplicate-notes-issues-in-mountain-lion/), but all your notes will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Would you add this as a answer so I can approve it?

Comment: Updated the answer. So the iCloud’s notes remain intact?

Comment: I have disabled icloud sync for notes a while ago because I taught this would cause the problem. I'll re-enable it and check back here.

Comment: Okay. I tested it. It still creates lots and lots of duplicates :( Well I guess I'll have to ditch notes.app and search for another app. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Try Simplenote, it has a nice app for both iOS and Mac.

Comment: That Simplenote is nice. I'm gonna be using this from now on :D thanks for the hint.